# How can I change a Slider's appearance?

Tags: graphics, dynamic, gui-construction

I am using *Mathematica* 9.0 and Windows 7. I want to create a `Slider` that looks like the following:

[image]

I tried the following:

```
Slider[Dynamic[n], {1, 9, 1}, Appearance -> Large,
    ImageSize -> {300, 40}, ContinuousAction -> False, Background -> Black]
```

and got this:

[image]

How can I get this to look like the first image?

Comment: It doesn't answer your question directly but you might be able to combine `LocatorPane` with `DynamicModule` to do what you want. See the help section on `LocatorPane' with some examples which might help.

Comment: @JonathanShock but in the below link output @Verbeia got same `slider`(what I want) without combining the both `locatorPane` and `DynamicModule`.why he got it like that?`http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1373/how-to-create-interrelated-sliders`

Comment: I don't see the `Slider` you want in the link you have written there. It appears to be a regular grey `Slider`.

Comment: @subbu, you need to get a Mac for that kind of slider:)

Comment: Sliders and other GUI controllers are rendered by the platform you are using: they look different depending on whether you are on OSX, Win or something else.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20496/121

Answer (score 10):

If pre-version-9 (no gauges yet), one has to rely on custom built controllers. 
Here is a slider implementation using `LocatorPane` (I prefer lines with rounded caps instead of rectangles because of aspect ratio issues):

```
slider[Dynamic[var_], {min_, max_}] := Module[{x = 0},
   LocatorPane[
    Dynamic[{x, 0}, (x = First@#; var = Rescale[x, {-1, 1}, {min, max}]) &], 
    Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness@6, CapForm@"Round", Line[{{-1, 0}, {1, 0}}]},
     ImageSize -> {300, 30}, 
     AspectRatio -> .1, PlotRangePadding -> 0], 
    Appearance -> Graphics[{EdgeForm@{Thick, Black}, White, Disk@{x, 0}}, 
      ImageSize -> 20]]];

{slider[Dynamic@x, {-100, 100}], Dynamic@x}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The very same with `Locator` (an extra `Clip` was necessary to prevent out-of-range values):

```
slider2[Dynamic[var_], {min_, max_}] := Module[{x = 0},
   Graphics[{
     AbsoluteThickness@6, CapForm@"Round", Line[{{-1, 0}, {1, 0}}],
     Locator[
      Dynamic[{x, 0}, (x = Clip[First@#, {-1, 1}]; var = Rescale[x, {-1, 1}, {min, max}]) &],
      Graphics[{EdgeForm@{Thick, Black}, White, Disk@{x, 0}}, 
       ImageSize -> 20, AspectRatio -> 1]]
     }, ImageSize -> {300, 30}, AspectRatio -> .1, 
    PlotRangePadding -> .1]];

{slider2[Dynamic@x, {-100, 100}], Dynamic@x}
```

Even simpler implementation with `EventHandler` and `Point` (to fully eliminate dependency on aspect ratio).

```
x = .5;
Graphics[{
  AbsoluteThickness@6, CapForm@"Round", Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}],
  EventHandler[
   {Black, AbsolutePointSize@20, Dynamic@Point@{x, 0},
    White, AbsolutePointSize@15, Dynamic@Point@{x, 0}},
   "MouseDragged" :> {x = Clip[First@MousePosition@"Graphics", {0, 1}]}]},
 ImageSize -> {200, 20}, AspectRatio -> .1]
```

Comment: Is it possible to include `Appearance -> Labeled` and make it editable as in the normal `Slider`? The editable part seems to be tricky since I can't do it over a dynamic label, for example, but maybe there's a more straightforward approach?

Answer (score 8):

You could always try a gauge:

```
gf[{{xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, ymax_}}, ___] := 
 {Black, 
  Rectangle[{xmin, -0.01}, {xmax, 0.01}, 
  RoundingRadius -> .01]}

HorizontalGauge[Dynamic[n], {1, 9},
 ScaleDivisions -> None,
 ScaleRanges -> All,
 ScaleRangeStyle -> None,
 GaugeFaceElementFunction -> gf,
 GaugeMarkers ->  Placed[
   Graphics[{Black, Disk[{0, 0}, 1],
      White, Disk[{0, 0}, .8]}], "Center"],
 ImageSize -> {400, 50}
 ]
```

The slight error in my code appears to give a cool 3D effect...

But I can't see why this would be worth doing...

[image: gauge]

Comment: +1 Nice, definitely gauges are better costomizable than sliders. Is the horizontal light line on the black bar something that `HorizontalGauge` adds, or is it just an export-artifact?

Comment: @IstvánZachar I can't work out what it is. It appears to be the line along which the marker moves, but I can't see what controls it...

Comment: @IstvánZachar and cormullion: Yes, that line is the path along which the marker moves. You can remove that line with `AxesStyle -> None` and also trim out the excess padding at the ends with `ScalePadding -> None`

Comment: @rm-rf ah yes, I forgot that gauges have all the `Graphics` options too...

Comment: @rm-rf That is strange, as the default for `HorizontalGauge` is `Axes -> False`.

Comment: @IstvánZachar Yeah, I don't think you can trust them. It seems to have been sloppily implemented... For instance, the simplest gauge: `HorizontalGauge[50, {0, 100}]` supposedly has `AxesStyle -> {None, None}`, but try entering that as an explicit option and it complains.