# Appearance of a slider

Tags: slider

I just observed that in Mathematica 10.3 for Windows the appearance of a slider has been changed. The slider is now blue, black when the mouse is over the slider and gray when the slider is dragged. For me, this blue is too striking, so I would like to change it. In the options of `Slider` I see that there must be a `DefaultBaseStyle` for a `Slider`, but I was unable to find the corresponding style definitions. Is there a way to find and adapt these definitions, e.g. with `CurrentValue`?

Comment: hmm, I don't see on Win 7 V 10.3.1 what you see. p.s. controllers definitions are somewhere in text resources as Graphics.

Comment: @Kuba. I see this on two computers, each running Windows 10, Mathematica version 10.3.1. On one of them I installed 10.3.1 only two days ago.

Comment: Would you please include screen captures so we can see what you're talking about?

Comment: Since Kuba is running Windows 7 and hasn't noticed anything, this probably has something to do with Windows 10 as well.  Have you tried changing OS style settings to see how they affect this?

Comment: A quick search for "Windows 10 slider" leads me to believe that blue is the new style in that version of Windows: http://cdn.pureinfotech.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/windows-10-control-color_large.jpg?681c7a

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. Yes, as usual you are right. Last week I upgraded both computers from Windows 7 to Windows 10, and that also explains why I did not observe the change earlier. I have never tried to make a screen capture, but in Mathematica my slider now looks exactly as the one in your reference. So it seems that Mathematica does not have settings for the slider and just takes the settings of the OS?  How to overcome that?

Comment: I know of no way to force the built-in control objects (e.g. `Slider`) to use a non-OS style.  You can however craft your own `Dynamic` `Graphics` expressions to do the job.  See: [(20496)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20496/121).  In fact I think this question can be a considered a duplicate of that one; would you oppose my closing it as such?

Comment: On second thought I guess building a slider would be more complicated and deserves its own Q&A.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. My question is not really to construct my own slider, but more on what can be done with the option DefaultBaseStyle.  I could not find any information for this option. Your reference 20496 includes the answer to my question: set BaseStyle->ControlsRendering->"Generic". Do you mind to formulate this as an answer, maybe also adressing DefaultBaseStyle?

Comment: You could post a self-answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use the wrapper `Style[ expr , ControlsRendering -> "Generic" ]` or as has been stated in the comments use the option [`BaseStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BaseStyle.html?q=BaseStyle):

```
Style[
    Manipulate[
       Null,
       {{a,1},1,10,1}
    ],
    ControlsRendering -> "Generic"
]
```

[image: Generic rendering]

Comment: @grw, this may be useful in some cases where Manipulate should not be wrapped: `Manipulate[Null, 
 Style[Control[{{a, 1}, 1, 10, 1}], ControlsRendering -> "Generic"]]`